# Prove that half-ellipsoid is convex

Tags: proof-explanation, convex-analysis, ellipsoids

> Let $$ S := \left\{ (x , y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + 2y^2 + 3z^2 \leq 6, x \geq 0 \right\} $$ Prove that $S$ is convex.

---

I have chosen two points: $\mathbf{(x_1, y_1, z_1)}$ and $\mathbf{(x_2, y_2, z_2)}$ $\in$ S.

And utilized the "line segment technique": **$\lambda$x + (1 - λ)y**, where $\lambda$ $\in$ [0,1]

In this case ($\mathbb{R}^3$), it gives:

$\lambda$$x_1$+(1-$\lambda$)$x_2$, $\lambda$$y_1$+(1-$\lambda$)$y_2$, $\lambda$$z_1$+(1-$\lambda$)$z_2$

Plugging into S:

($\lambda$$x_1$+(1-$\lambda$)$x_2$)$^2$ + 2($\lambda$$y_1$+(1-$\lambda$)$y_2$)$^2$ + 3($\lambda$$z_1$+(1-$\lambda$)$z_2$)$^2$

Expanding:

($\lambda$$^2$$x_1^2$+2(1-$\lambda$)$\lambda$$x_1$$x_2$+(1-$\lambda$)$^2$$x_2^2$) + 2($\lambda$$^2$$y_1^2$+2(1-$\lambda$)$\lambda$$y_1$$y_2$+(1-$\lambda$)$^2$$y_2^2$) + 3($\lambda$$^2$$z_1^2$+2(1-$\lambda$)$\lambda$$z_1$$z_2$+(1-$\lambda$)$^2$$z_2^2$)

Common factors give:

$\lambda$$^2$($x_1^2$+2$y_1^2$+3$z_1^2$) + 2$\lambda$(1-$\lambda$)($x_1$$x_2$+2$y_1$$y_2$ + 3$z_1$$z_2$) + (1-$\lambda$)$^2$($x_2^2$+2$y_2^2$+3$z_2^2$)

From S, it follows that ($x_1^2$+2$y_1^2$+3$z_1^2$) and ($x_2^2$+2$y_2^2$+3$z_2^2$) $\leq$ 6, which gives

$\lambda$$^2$(6) + 2$\lambda$(1-$\lambda$)($x_1$$x_2$+2$y_1$$y_2$ + 3$z_1$$z_2$) + (1-$\lambda$)$^2$(6)

If we also assume that ($x_1$$x_2$+2$y_1$$y_2$ + 3$z_1$$z_2$) $\leq$ 6, we get

$\lambda$$^2$(6) + 2$\lambda$(1-$\lambda$)(6) + (1-$\lambda$)$^2$(6)

Solving this gives:

6, which is $\leq$ 6 and thus the set needs to be convex. But here my problem arises:

**How can we know that** ($x_1$$x_2$+2$y_1$$y_2$ + 3$z_1$$z_2$) **is indeed $\leq$ 6?**

Any help appreciated!

Comment: use $ab \le (a^2+b^2)/2$

Comment: Where does this come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in $\mathbb{R}^3$ :
$(x_1 x_2+2y_1y_2 + 3z_1z_2)= \\
\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ \sqrt{2}y_1 \\  \sqrt{3}z_1 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}x_2\\ \sqrt{2}y_2 \\  \sqrt{3}z_2 \end{pmatrix} \leq 
\sqrt{(x_1)^2 +(\sqrt{2}y_1)^2+(\sqrt{3}z_1)^2}
\sqrt{(x_2)^2 +(\sqrt{2}y_2)^2+(\sqrt{3}z_2)^2}  \\
=    
\sqrt{x_1^2 +2y_1^2+3z_1^2}
\sqrt{x_2^2 +2y_2^2+3z_2^2} \leq \sqrt{6} \sqrt{6} = 6
$

Comment: Bingo, that's it! Thanks!